# Magento 2.1 get custom options for related products

Tags: magento2

At product details page we have product name, price, sku etc... for related products but how can we get custom options?

Comment: You can Refer this one.. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147935/how-can-i-get-custom-options-from-product-in-magento-2

Comment: @Jimit Bhavsar, have you solved your problem? if yes then please share your solution here. I have too get custom options in related product section.

Comment: @H_Parekh using product id we can get custom option as given below code, but my requirement is different and for that i haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $o) {
    if ($o->getTitle() != 'Color') { // or another title of option
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
        print_r($value->getData());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1: Create object manager**

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

**Step 2: Generate the product**
Generate the product that need to be assigned custom options.

```
$product = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
```

**Step 3: Custom options**

```
$customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
```

**Step 4: Configurable Options**

```
$productTypeInstance = $_objectManager->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');
         $productAttributeOptions = $productTypeInstance->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
```

Thank you.